# MySQL outputting to many <option> elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form that load into a page via ajax. The form works fine but I have select input in the form that is populated by a mysql call to get the values that should be in the drop down. This is working but the select looks like this.

```
<select>
<option value="1">Name</option>
<option></option>
<option value="2">Position</option>
```

and it repeats the extra option tag with nothing in it causing spacing issues on the form.

Here is the form code:

```
<form id="company-form" action="scripts/create-library.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button id="hide-form"><img src="images/minus.png"/></button>
    <h3>Add Library Item Form</h3>
    <input class="c-name" type="text" name="file-display-name" placeholder="File Display Name"/>
    <select class="companies-dd" name="companies">
        <?php
            require_once("../../scripts/connection.php");

            // Select all companies and related data
            $sql = "SELECT company_id, company FROM companies ORDER BY company_id";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($c_id, $c);
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<option value='".$c_id."'>".$c."<option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input id="uploadFile" class="image-name" type="text" name="library-file-name" placeholder="No Logo File Chosen" disabled="disabled"/>
    <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" name="library-file"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

here is the ajax call on the page it loads into:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
            $(document).on('click','#add',function(){   
                var form_fetch = $(this).attr('name');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "include/forms/add-"+form_fetch+"-form.php", success: function(result){
                        $('#section-form').html(result);
                        }, error: function (){
                            $('#section-form').html("<p>The Form could not be either loaded or found. Please try again later or contact the web developer.</p>");
                        }
                });
            });
});
```

the section-form is just a blank section on the page with no content until something is loaded into it. I have another form working fine but it does not use the dropdown select. Why is the query rendering an extra echo of the option?

Comment: `<option>` is a typo. `</option>`.

Comment: As a bit of advice, consider limiting your use of `echo` when outputting HTML. Instead, your `while` loop could contain `{ ?> <option value="<?=$c_id?>"><?=$c?></option> <? }` -- while this may look ugly here, it's very helpful to allow your IDE to syntax-highlight your HTML and bracket-match your tags - this would have revealed the issue right away ^^

Comment: ^ although generally I'd agree with that (like for multiple lines of html) in this case, I think the echo is cleaner.

Comment: Thank you I will take this advice in for consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html is malformed, you're missing the closing slash in the option tag

```
echo "<option value='".$c_id."'>".$c."</option>";
```

Comment: Wow. I feel like an idiot. Thank you I just couldnt see that I guess I was thinking that in my head but not seeing it.

Comment: For your reference, @Musa, there is a close-vote reason specifically for typo questions - we should close them (and leave a comment explaining the typo), not post an answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you're creating two `option` tags each iteration instead of closing them:

```
echo "<option value='".$c_id."'>".$c."<option>";
```

It should be:

```
echo "<option value='".$c_id."'>".$c."</option>";
```